# Getting "hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character" in correct Japanese XML

Tags: xml, powershell, utf-8, cjk

All, I'm getting

> hexadecimal value 0x3C, is an invalid attribute character

error while trying to read XML on computer with Japanese locale and Japanese characters in the file:

```
  $xml = [xml]@(Get-Content $file)
```

Specific place in the XML is pretty benign:

```
<Control type="select">
```

As far as I can tell almost every error like that is caused by "<" somewhere in the string. So I checked my XML and did not see any extra "<" where it shouldn't be. 
But then I've found one [hotfix description](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2787651/error-when-you-run-the-best-practices-analyzer-tool-on-a-computer-that) that says this:

> Consider the following scenario: You have a computer that is running Windows Server 2012. The system locale setting of the computer is set
>   to Japanese. You install the Network Policy and Access Services (NPAS)
>   server role with default settings on the computer. You try to run the
>   Best Practices Analyzer tool to scan Network Access Protection (NAP)
>   components.

Kinda sounds familiar, so I suspect it's due to Japanese locale or due to Japanese characters in some of the values for the XML.

The file itself starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the document _actually_ `utf-8` encoded?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Notepad++ says it's UTF-8, all Japanese characters are displayed correctly.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen thanks for the comment though, it prompted me to check if I can explicitly specify encoding when getting content and there is such an option with `Get-Content`

Comment: Sounds like it's utf8 no bom.

Comment: What does the xml look like?  0x3c is "<" in ascii.

Comment: I don't think that's the whole error message.  I think 0x3c is part of the utf8 encoding of a japanese character inside the name of an attribute.  Since powershell 5 thinks it's ascii, it takes each byte as one character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped in this case was explicitly specifying encoding when getting file contents:

```
 $xml = [xml]@(Get-Content $file -Encoding UTF8)
```

Comment: Nice, though it's much more efficient to use `$xml = [xml] (Get-Content -Raw $file -Encoding UTF8)`, because it reads the file as a whole rather than as array of lines. Also, you wouldn't need `-Encoding UTF8` in PowerShell _Core_ (v6+), where it is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a demo of how this can happen.  This file.xml has one japanese character encoded in utf8 no bom:

```
<こ/>
```

That character is unicode 0x3053:

```
[int][char]'こ' | % tostring x

3053
```

```
'こ' | format-hex -Encoding bigendianunicode


   Label: String (System.String) <32532FE4>

          Offset Bytes                                           Ascii
                 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F
          ------ ----------------------------------------------- -----
0000000000000000 30 53                                           0S
```

Powershell 5 will assume the file is ascii:

```
[xml]$xml = get-content file.xml

Cannot convert value "<ã“/>" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The '' character,
hexadecimal value 0x81, cannot be included in a name. Line 1, position 3."
At line:1 char:1
+ [xml]$xml = get-content file.xml
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Unicode character 0x3053 will get encoded in utf8 as 3 bytes, "E3 81 93", because of the range it falls in.  The utf8 bit prefixes look like this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).  Three bytes always begin with '1110' or 'E'.  The other '10' bits continue it.

```
1110xxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx
```

Xml doesn't mind the E3 because it's an a with a squiggly line above it, but the 81 just looks like an empty box (stackoverflow can't display it), so it causes an error.  Here are the raw bytes of the file.xml.  "0D 0A" is just carriage return and linefeed.

```
format-hex file.xml -encoding utf8


           Path: C:\Users\admin\foo\file.xml

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   3C E3 81 93 2F 3E 0D 0A                          <ã“/>..
```

I don't know how exactly to reproduce the op's error, but it's something like that.